# jQuery UI is not animating addClass (I have jsfiddle example)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I'm crafting a menu. I am using jQ UI and it should animate .addClass but it's not animating... What am I doing wrong?
here is my code:

```
$(".items li:not(.testAct)").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("testHov", 1000, "easeIn");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("testHov", 1000, "easeIn");
    }
);
```

here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexlime/ZR5Zp/1/)

Comment: Nothing happens even if you just give these items the testHov class..

Comment: I just want to make those upper stripes to fade in a little

Comment: I think it's not working because I'm adding a pseudo class ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some mistakes on your CSS and JS.

There's no "easeIn" [easing](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), so this was wrong:

```
$(this).addClass("testHov", 1000, "easeIn");
```

Also, the `after` pseudo class didn't help you get what you want.

Here's a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZR5Zp/6/

Comment: But I need this upper border elements to appear exactly on the top of the main black upper border.

Comment: @Alex: Look now at my new link

Comment: Clever. Negative margin. )) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

made some changes and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZR5Zp/4/

```
$(".items li:not(.testAct)").hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass("testHov", 1000, "easeInBounce");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("testHov", 1000, "easeInBounce");
}
);
```

css:

```
.testHov {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
```

Comment: Using the `after` pseudo class is unnecessary here (I know that it was already there) and ruins the whole thing